# "Has yet to be a total success."

Tags: phrases

What does mean a sentence "Intervention that has yet to be a total success"?

Does it mean the success is not total or that there will be total success soon?
Or the total success was planned but difficult to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

On its face the phrase carries the implication that total success is expected but has not happened yet.  In the context of the Western intervention in Libya (where I suspect you saw the phrase), fighting is continuing in Sirte and Bani Walid but may end soon.

However, tone is important, and it may sometimes be used as a gentler way of saying that the  intervention has been a disaster.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "has yet to be a total success" could be alternately expressed as *"has yet to totally succeed."*

The inclusion of the word *yet* by the speaker tells us that, from his/her perspective, success is imminent.

Objectively, this may or may not be true. For example, an overly confident manufacturer could use this phrase to soften the news of a product's failure, even if it's clear that the product will likely never be a success.

The phrase does not give any clues as to why success hasn't yet occurred. It simply informs us that the speaker believes that, despite the delay, success is still expected.

Comment: It could also be a sarcastic remark by somoene who doubted it would ever be a success.

Comment: Yes, that's also true.

Comment: Taken literally, the phrase would mean that complete success is expected but has not yet been achieved. But in practice, I think this phrase is almost always used sarcastically to mean that the effort has failed badly.